# ForEach-Object at command pipeline position Problem

Tags: powershell

I've got the below Powershell script, and I'm struggling to finish it off.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\temp\xml' -Include '*.xml' |
    ForEach-Object 
    {
        $FileName = $_.Fullname
    $Pattern = "</Date>"  
    $FileOriginal = Get-Content $FileName
    $date = Get-Date
    $DateStr = $date.ToString("yyyyMMdd")

    [String[]] $FileModified = @() 
    Foreach ($Line in $FileOriginal)
    {   
        $FileModified += $Line
        if ($Line -match $pattern) 
        {
        $FileModified += "<CDate>$DateStr</CDate>"

        } 
    }
    $FileModified = $FileModified -replace "CUR","PIT"
    $FileModified = $FileModified -replace "Current","Time"
    Set-Content $fileName $FileModified   
    }
```

When I attempt to run it, I get the following messages:

```
cmdlet ForEach-Object at command pipeline position 2
Supply values for the following parameters:
Process[0]:
```

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You have to put the brace on the same line of foreach-object

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put the curly brace on the same line as the foreach-object:

```
echo hi | foreach-object {
  $_
}
```

This would fail, even in a script.  It's a cmdlet, not a statement like "if", so it needs its -Process parameter on the same line.

```
echo hi | foreach-object 
{
  $_
}
```

Comment: That simple! Odd that it doesn't pick up any of the XML files and doesnt even go into the loop. Anything obvious there?

Comment: @Philip It's lame.  -include only works with -recurse or a wildcard in -path.